# EditText becomes null on other methods

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-edittext, object-reference

In **myfragment class** witch extends **Fragment** I'm finding object reference in **onCreateView** method

```
private static final String TAG = "CloadLab";


private Cloud dCloud;
private EditText dNameText;
public String dNameHolder = "";




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    UUID dreamId = (UUID)getArguments().getSerializable(EXTRA_DREAM_ID);




}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    getActivity().setTitle("Add new");

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add,parent,false);

    dNameText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.dream_name);


    return v;
}

public void SaveDream (){


    dNameHolder = dNameText.getText().toString();

    if (dNameText != null) {
        Log.e(TAG,"not null");
    }else if (dNameText == null){
        Log.e(TAG,"null");
    }


}
```

}

which works fine if I use it within **onCreateView** method, but for example I want to use **dNameText** in this method which is in same class

```
public void SaveDream (){
   dNameHolder = dNameText.getText().toString();
}
```

and now it has null object reference how can I fix that and how can I set references through whole class?

I'm calling this **SaveDream()** method from Activity which holds this Fragment

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.action_favorite:

            AddFragment mActivity= new AddFragment();
            mActivity.SaveDream();
            finish();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


}
```

Every **Activity** extends **SingleFragmentActivity** and has these methods in it

```
        private AddFragment mFragment;

@Override
    protected Fragment createFragment() {

    UUID dreamId = (UUID)getIntent()
            .getSerializableExtra(AddFragment.EXTRA_DREAM_ID);
    return AddFragment.newInstance(dreamId);
}

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_bar_menu,menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.action_favorite:

               // AddFragment mActivity= new AddFragment();
               // mActivity.SaveDream();
                //finish();
                mFragment = new AddFragment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, mFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                mFragment.SaveDream();
                finish();
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


    }
```

**SingleFragmentActivity**

```
    protected abstract Fragment createFragment();

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

   // getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);


    if (fragment == null){
        fragment = createFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
                .commit();
    }

}
```

Comment: From where do you call `SaveDream`?

Comment: from Activity which holds this fragment

Comment: Can you show me how are you calling this?

Comment: added method to main post

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `SaveDream` method on a new instance of the fragment, not the one which is loaded right now at

```
AddFragment mActivity= new AddFragment();
mActivity.SaveDream();
```

Because the view is not created on the new instance (view is created while loading) and you are getting null for `EditText`. You should keep the loaded instance globally and call the method on that instance.

Follow these steps.

**Step 1:** Create a class level variable

```
private AddFragment mFragment;
```

**Step 2:** Load Fragment like this

```
mFragment = new AddFragment();

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, mFragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

**Step 3:** Call method like this

```
mFragment.SaveDream();
```

**Update**

Update method like this

```
@Override
protected Fragment createFragment() {
    UUID dreamId = (UUID)getIntent()
        .getSerializableExtra(AddFragment.EXTRA_DREAM_ID);
    mFragment = AddFragment.newInstance(dreamId);
    return mFragment;
}
```

and

```
case R.id.action_favorite:
    mFragment.SaveDream();
    return true;
```

Comment: So I need to load Fragment with Step 2 to that activity to use SaveDream() method?

Comment: @kosas Keep loading the fragment the way are doing it right now. Just keep the reference of loaded fragment and use that reference to call the `saveDream` method.

Comment: Ok I just done it, SaveDream() method works but still I get that EditText is null

Comment: Can you show me how you are loading the fragment and update code for calling the method?

Comment: You are awesome dude !!